# C# fill List<T> with strings from another class with default constructor

Tags: c#

I currently have two classes Item and ItemManager in ItemManager class i have created a List that can be filled with Item ( List ItemList = new List();  ). I now want to fill this list with strings from a private array located in Item using only a default constructor ie no parameters. Is this possible and if so how to do it?

```
class ItemManager
{
    List<ShoppingItem> ItemList = new List<ShoppingItem>();

    public void GetDrinks()
    {
        Item item = new Item();

        for (int i = 0; i < item.GetProductsAt(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetProducts()[i]);
        }
        ItemList.Add(item);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

class Item:

```
public class Item
{
    private string[] products = { "Milk", "Meat", "Toothbrush", "Chicken", "Pepper" };

    public Item()
    {
    }
    public string[] GetProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }
    public int GetProductsAt()
    {
        return products.Length;
    }
}



Output: MilkMeatToothbrushChickenPepper
```

I can see that the List (ItemList) contains the array but im unable to write it to the console using the list instead of how im doing it now. Help, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fill ItemList variable in ItemManager class with strings in private products variable of class Item then you will have to declare ItemList as `List<string> ItemList = new List<string>` instead of `List<ShoppingItem> ItemList = new List<ShoppingItem>();`. Below is a sample console application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Console_Example
{
    public class Item
    {
        private string[] products = { "Milk", "Meat", "Toothbrush", "Chicken", "Pepper" };

        public Item()
        {
        }
        public string[] GetProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }
        public int GetProductsAt()
        {
            return products.Length;
        }
    }

    class ItemManager
    {
        //List<ShoppingItem> ItemList = new List<ShoppingItem>();
        List<string> ItemList;

        public void GetDrinks()
        {
            //Item item = new Item();

            //for (int i = 0; i < item.GetProductsAt(); i++)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(item.GetProducts()[i]);
            //}
            //ItemList.Add(item);
            //Console.ReadLine();

            Item item = new Item();
            ItemList = new List<string>(item.GetProducts());

            foreach (string str in ItemList)
            {
                Console.Write(str);
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ItemManager itemManager = new ItemManager();
            itemManager.GetDrinks();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```